# How do I return all current ekevents?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, ekevent

I have some sample code that I need to modify but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
// Fetch all events happening in the next 24 hours 
- (NSMutableArray *)fetchEvents
{
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    //Create the end date components
    NSDateComponents *tomorrowDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    tomorrowDateComponents.day = 1;

    NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowDateComponents
                                                                    toDate:startDate
                                                                   options:0];
    // We will only search the default calendar for our events
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.defaultCalendar];

    // Create the predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                      endDate:endDate
                                                                    calendars:calendarArray];

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];

    return events;
}
```

I need to modify this so that it returns all current events. That is, all events that started in the past AND end in the future, relative to the current moment- all events occurring right now.

This is my first ios app... can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Modify `startDate` so it's in the past. Look at how the `endDate` is constructed—where `tomorrowDateComponents.day` is assigned a positive number of days, you can also use a negative number to go to an earlier date.